# How to assign a Future[Option[Int]] to a OptionT[Future, Int]

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I created this simple Monad Transformer

```
type FutureOptionInt = OptionT[Future, Int]
```

now I can easily create a instance of this via

```
1.pure[FutureOptionInt]
```

this is good. but I have another function which is returning me a Future[Option[Int]]. I cannot change the output of this function to MT

so I need to assign the return type to my MT.

I tried

```
val y = Future(Option(1))
val x : FutureOptionInt = y
```

but I get error

```
cmd5.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Some[Int]]
 required: $sess.cmd3.FutureOption
    (which expands to)  cats.data.OptionT[scala.concurrent.Future,Int]
val x : FutureOption = y
```

So the question is that if you have a Future[Option[Int]] how do you assign it to OptionT[Future, Int]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an implicit conversion to do this:

```
implicit def toTransformer(future: Future[Option[Int]]) = OptionT(future)
```

Then the assignment you had works.

It may also be useful for you to abstract over what's inside the option as follows so you don't have to write loads of converters:

```
implicit def toTransformer[T](future: Future[Option[T]]) = OptionT(future)

type FutureOpt[T] = OptionT[Future, T]

val intOpt = Future(Option(1))
val strOpt = Future(Option(""))

val x : FutureOpt[Int] = intOpt
val y : FutureOpt[String] = strOpt
```